# Quale preposizione usare dopo "comprare"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Perché si dice "comprare *dei*" qualcosa? Perché si deve usare la preposizione *di*?

Comment: Collegato: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6027/the-della-in-vorrei-delluva

Comment: Benvenuto sul sito!

Answer (score 7):

Si dice “comprare il giornale”, “comprare un libro”. Si *può* dire “comprare delle uova”. In questo caso “delle” è l'articolo partitivo, in sostanza il plurale dell'articolo indeterminativo.

Vedi [l'articolo sull'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/partitivo_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29%2F)